# Bash on Windows (10) doesn't recognize the installed version of node

Tags: node.js, bash, windows-10, version

I have installed Bash on my Windows 10 PC.
Then I downloaded and installed the newest version of node (v6.10.2).
Using the windows command line and typing "node -v" it tells me, that node v.6.10.2 is installed.
Using the Bash command line and again typing "node-v" the output tells me that node v0.10.25 is installed.

How can I get Bash to recognize the new version of node?

Without the new version I cannot download any modules from npm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out where is the new Node installed and add it to your PATH in Bash before the place where the old Node is installed.

For example, if your new Node is in `/a/b/c/node.exe` (is it still exe on Windows?) then you need to do:

```
export PATH="/a/b/c:$PATH"
```

in Bash. You should add it to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` if you want the change to be persistent.

Keep in mind that you probably need to use the path as recognized in Bash - probably using forward slashes and directories for partitions etc.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! In the end I noticed that it is even better to use "root" as a user. Root has access to all those files.

Comment: Actually it didn't work in the next step. It was becuase bash was not started as administrator. Before you open bash right-click it and then start it as administrator

Comment: but it should be a Windows exe right? If we install Ubuntu shell everything needs to be installed under Linux?